# Unable to draw within scrolled window in gtk3

Tags: c, linux, gtk3

I am migrating from gtk2 to gtk3, and am unable to draw within a scrolled window. Please note that I am using gtk version 3.10, and need to stick with that version and not a newer version, so please don’t provide an explanation for a newer version. I have included full code for both gtk2, gtk3, and the makefile. In gtk2 it produces a red square in both the left and right drawing area, but in gtk3 only the left square shows. What am I doing wrong (or not doing right)?

test2.c

```
    // GTK2
// test2.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <cairo.h>

GtkWidget *left_drawing_area;
GtkWidget *right_drawing_area;
int lcounter = 0;
int rcounter = 0;

static gboolean left_expose_event(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventExpose *event, gpointer data)
{
  lcounter++;
  printf ("drawing left %d\n", lcounter);
  cairo_t *cr;
  double x, y, w, l, r, g, b;
  cr = gdk_cairo_create(left_drawing_area->window);
  int color = 0xFF0000;  // red
  b = (double)(color & 0xff) / 255;
  g = (double)( (color >> 8) & 0xff) / 255;
  r = (double)( (color >> 16) & 0xff) / 255;
  x = 0;
  y = 0;
  w = 50;
  l = 50;
  cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, r, g, b);
  cairo_rectangle(cr, x, y, w, l);
  cairo_fill(cr);
  return 0;
}

static gboolean right_expose_event(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventExpose *event, gpointer data)
{
  rcounter++;
  printf ("drawing right %d\n", rcounter);
  gtk_widget_set_size_request (GTK_WIDGET (right_drawing_area), 400, 1000);
  cairo_t *cr;
  double x, y, w, l, r, g, b;
  cr = gdk_cairo_create(right_drawing_area->window);
  int color = 0xFF0000;  // red
  b = (double)(color & 0xff) / 255;
  g = (double)( (color >> 8) & 0xff) / 255;
  r = (double)( (color >> 16) & 0xff) / 255;
  x = 0;
  y = 0;
  w = 50;
  l = 50;
  cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, r, g, b);
  cairo_rectangle(cr, x, y, w, l);
  cairo_fill(cr);
  return 0;
}


int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
  GtkWidget *main_window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(main_window), 800, 600);
  gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(main_window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);

  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(main_window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  GtkWidget *main_hbox = gtk_hbox_new (FALSE, 0);
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (main_window), main_hbox);

  GtkWidget *left_vbox = gtk_vbox_new (FALSE, 0);
  gtk_widget_set_size_request (GTK_WIDGET (left_vbox), 100, -1);
  gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (main_hbox), left_vbox, FALSE, FALSE, 0);

  left_drawing_area = gtk_drawing_area_new();
  gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (left_vbox), left_drawing_area, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

  g_signal_connect(left_drawing_area, "expose-event", G_CALLBACK(left_expose_event), NULL);

  GtkWidget *right_vbox = gtk_vbox_new (FALSE, 0);
  gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (main_hbox), right_vbox, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

  GtkWidget *scrolled_window = gtk_scrolled_window_new (NULL, NULL);
  gtk_scrolled_window_set_policy (GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW (scrolled_window), GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC, GTK_POLICY_ALWAYS);
  gtk_widget_set_usize(scrolled_window, 400, 300);
  gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (right_vbox), scrolled_window, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

  right_drawing_area = gtk_drawing_area_new();
  gtk_scrolled_window_add_with_viewport(GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW(scrolled_window), right_drawing_area);
  gtk_widget_set_size_request (GTK_WIDGET (right_drawing_area), 200, 200);

  g_signal_connect(right_drawing_area, "expose-event", G_CALLBACK(right_expose_event), NULL);

  gtk_widget_show_all(main_window);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

test3.c

```
    // GTK3 (version 3.10)
// test3.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <cairo.h>

GtkWidget *left_drawing_area;
GtkWidget *right_drawing_area;
int lcounter = 0;
int rcounter = 0;

static gboolean left_expose_event(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventExpose *event, gpointer data)
{
  lcounter++;
  printf ("drawing left %d\n", lcounter);
  cairo_t *cr;
  double x, y, w, l, r, g, b;
  cr = gdk_cairo_create(gtk_widget_get_window(left_drawing_area));
  int color = 0xFF0000;  // red
  b = (double)(color & 0xff) / 255;
  g = (double)( (color >> 8) & 0xff) / 255;
  r = (double)( (color >> 16) & 0xff) / 255;
  x = 0;
  y = 0;
  w = 50;
  l = 50;
  cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, r, g, b);
  cairo_rectangle(cr, x, y, w, l);
  cairo_fill(cr);
  return 0;
}

static gboolean right_expose_event(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventExpose *event, gpointer data)
{
  rcounter++;
  printf ("drawing right %d\n", rcounter);
  gtk_widget_set_size_request (GTK_WIDGET (right_drawing_area), 400, 1000);
  cairo_t *cr;
  double x, y, w, l, r, g, b;
  cr = gdk_cairo_create(gtk_widget_get_window(right_drawing_area));
  int color = 0xFF0000;  // red
  b = (double)(color & 0xff) / 255;
  g = (double)( (color >> 8) & 0xff) / 255;
  r = (double)( (color >> 16) & 0xff) / 255;
  x = 0;
  y = 0;
  w = 50;
  l = 50;
  cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, r, g, b);
  cairo_rectangle(cr, x, y, w, l);
  cairo_fill(cr);
  return 0;
}


int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
  GtkWidget *main_window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(main_window), 800, 600);
  gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(main_window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);

  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(main_window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  GtkWidget *main_hbox = gtk_hbox_new (FALSE, 0);
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (main_window), main_hbox);

  GtkWidget *left_vbox = gtk_vbox_new (FALSE, 0);
  gtk_widget_set_size_request (GTK_WIDGET (left_vbox), 100, -1);
  gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (main_hbox), left_vbox, FALSE, FALSE, 0);

  left_drawing_area = gtk_drawing_area_new();
  gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (left_vbox), left_drawing_area, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

  g_signal_connect(left_drawing_area, "draw", G_CALLBACK(left_expose_event), NULL);

  GtkWidget *right_vbox = gtk_vbox_new (FALSE, 0);
  gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (main_hbox), right_vbox, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

  GtkWidget *scrolled_window = gtk_scrolled_window_new (NULL, NULL);
  gtk_scrolled_window_set_policy (GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW (scrolled_window), GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC, GTK_POLICY_ALWAYS);
  gtk_widget_set_size_request(scrolled_window, 400, 300);
  gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (right_vbox), scrolled_window, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

  right_drawing_area = gtk_drawing_area_new();
  gtk_scrolled_window_add_with_viewport(GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW(scrolled_window), right_drawing_area);
  gtk_widget_set_size_request (GTK_WIDGET (right_drawing_area), 200, 200);

  g_signal_connect(right_drawing_area, "draw", G_CALLBACK(right_expose_event), NULL);

  gtk_widget_show_all(main_window);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

makefile

```
    PKG2 = gtk+-2.0
CFLAGS2 += $(shell pkg-config --cflags $(PKG2))
LIBS2 = $(shell pkg-config --libs $(PKG2))

PKG3 = gtk+-3.0
CFLAGS3 += $(shell pkg-config --cflags $(PKG3))
LIBS3 = $(shell pkg-config --libs $(PKG3))

all: test2 test3

test2.o: test2.c
    cc -c $(CFLAGS2) "-DV=2" test2.c

test2: test2.o
    cc -o test2 test2.o $(LIBS2)

test3.o: test3.c
    cc -c $(CFLAGS3) "-DV=3" test3.c

test3: test3.o
    cc -o test3 test3.o $(LIBS3)

clean:
    rm -f *.o test2 test3
```

Comment: Wow, almost 2 full weeks and not one comment. That is not a good sign for me :(

Comment: This same exact code does work in gtk 3.23, although the drawing is a bit glitchy. So it would appear that version 3.10 is broken in this respect. That makes things difficult for me, but I guess I don't have a choice but to figure out how to use an updated version of gtk on the system I need to build on. That makes things much more difficult for me :(

Comment: I would also like to add that with version 3.10, when the main window is made big enough that the scrolled window is full size, the drawing is visible. But as soon as I shrink the main window the drawing disappears again.

Comment: Yet another road block. If I compile the program with gtk 3.23, the drawing does not show when the program is ran on an older OS with gtk 3.10. I think that is a sign that I need to forget about migrating to gtk3 and stick with gtk2.